# htaccess fails to redirect to subfolder when arriving from Bing.Com URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, bing

When I search for a relevant page (on my example.com domain) in Bing.Com, and click the URL that reads `example.com/subfolder2/file.html` it has this underlying long URL in Bing.Com:

`https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p= .... a very long random code ... &ntb=1`

My server returns the `missing.html` identified in the root htaccess.  This means old URLs in that search engine cache won't get fixed, and the user misses my content.

I have a .htaccess file on my root directory, and the intent is to do these things with permanent redirects

- move `example.com/subfolder/file.html` to `subfolder.example.com/file.html`
- move `example.com` to `www.example.com`
- return "index.html" if there is no file specified

Mostly successfully, I am using this .htaccess code in the root directory of example.com:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/missing.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/missing.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/missing.html

AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm .shtml .shtm
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews +Includes

DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#move to subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder1/(.*)$ http://subfolder1.example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder2/(.*)$ http://subfolder2.example.com/$1 [R=301]

#if missing sub-domain, add "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As expected, the URL `www.example.com/subfolder/file.html` works, returning `subfolder2.example.com/file.html`.   If I **type** `example.com/subfolder/file.html` on my browser, it also works.

What am I missing?

Noting: a) when I add htaccess code to the subfolder, it does nothing;   b) I have 7 different subdomains, each with their own rewrite rule, not two, so I am sure I am missing some efficiency in writing or executing the rewrites; c) I have HTTP service from my server; d) the cached version on Bing reports as `http://example.com/subfolder/file.html`, and; e) I might have run into this same quirky result from a Google search, but it has either washed away or I can't replicate/recall exactly what happened.

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure how reaching your URL via a search result differs from entering the URL directly. Is it actually the same URL - or do the search engines perhaps append tracking parameters, that your system somehow can't handle? You are not doing anything like checking on the referrer here, so I don't see what could cause this behavior. If you have full access to the server or at least vhost configuration, then I would enable some rewrite logging, and then check what happens in detail.

Comment: Specifying your ErrorDocuments with absolute URLs is not a good idea, btw. Apache will issue a _redirect_ for those URLs, and then after that clients will get a 200 OK status code, when they request your missing.html - so they will never get the _proper_ status code response.

Comment: As for your seven different subdomains, you can probably reduce the number of rules. I'm guessing it is not _actually_ numbers in the subdomain and folder names, but something else? Then you can work with alternation in the relevant places, `(abc|def)` would match either `abc` or `def`, and then you can use a back reference to insert that match into your host name for the redirect. (Assuming the variable part of the subdomain, is always same as in the folder name.)

Comment: @CBroe ... thanks for your input.    a) Bing supplies the long URL, and then its servers refer over.  I assume it's a method to track, and there is nothing i can do about it.  b) what is the alternative to the errorDocuments reference the you suggest?  c) i sort of get the matching issue, but it would help to have a sample line construct from you; i don't have a full handle on the syntax.   And then, D) as asides, should I be adding other codes inside the "[..]"? why don't lines in subfolder htaccess get executed?

Comment: b) relative URLs; starting with a / if you want to refer to your domain root. c) `RewriteRule ^/?(abc|def)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301]` d) not sure what you are talking about there.

Comment: d) ... retry: d1) I see codes like L and others that go into the sq. brackets; I was wondering what they do, in simple terms ; and d2) just wondering why I can never get the htaccess coding in any subfolder to work